# C++11 Type Traits: Arithmetic user type

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, usertype

Example:

```
struct IntWrapper { int x; operator int() const { return x; } ... }
static_assert(std::is_integral<IntWrapper>::value, "Invalid type.");
```

Is it possible to get std::is_integral<IntWrapper>::value to be true?

Thanks.

Comment: template specialization

Comment: So instead of including <type_traits> I should include "my_type_traits.hpp" right? It will include <type_traits> and any specialisations.

Comment: @BryanChen Adding a specialization for `is_integral` (and other type traits) is UB ([meta.type.synop]/1). Also violates [meta.unary.cat]/2 which states only one of the primary type category traits will yield true; in this case both `is_class` and `is_integral` would be true.

Comment: this is a bad idea.  don't do this.  your type is not an integral it is a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get `std::is_integral<IntWrapper>::value` to be true?

Yes, it is possible.  But not without creating undefined behavior.  I.e. when you try to do this, the resulting undefined behavior could be exactly what you want.  Or it could be most anything you don't want.  And testing won't help.

But all is not lost.  You can easily create your own trait to do what exactly what you want.  For example:

```
template <class T>
struct IsMyInt
    : std::is_integral<T>
{
};

template <>
struct IsMyInt<IntWrapper>
    : std::true_type
{
};

static_assert(IsMyInt<IntWrapper>::value, "Invalid type.");
```

`IsMyInt` behaves exactly as how you wished `std::is_integral` behaves, but without undefined behavior.  So now all you have to do is use `IsMyInt` instead of `std::is_integral`.

Comment: Thanks :) When I tried the 'std::' specialisation I immediately ran into problems. This solution works nicely.